# Regex in oracle SQL - return all numbers in a string, comma-delimited

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

My input value is something like:

```
Value:123 with subvalues:[134,135,136]
```

I just want to pull all of the numbers from this and keep them comma-delimited  if they are seperated by at least one non-digit character. I'm using this right now:

```
regexp_replace(message,  '[^[:digit:]]')
```

This pulls the numbers, but obviously replacing even the spaces between those numbers with nothing. How can I get the result of:

```
123,134,135,136
```

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like what you are doing should be addressed in the application logic, not in the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(
            'Value:123 with subvalues:[134,135,136]',
            '[^[:digit:]]+', ','),
        '^,+|,+$'
    ) as s
from dual;
```

**Result:**

```
s
---------------
123,134,135,136
```